# remove trailing slash in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/:year',
    component: Nav,
    children: [
      { path: '', name: 'test', component: Test }
    ]
  }
];
```

```
<!-- /2018/ -->
<router-link :to="{name: 'test', params: {year: 2018}}"></router-link>
```

If there are children, I want to remove trailing slash added to the path created by router-link.

Comment: Add this property to child route object `pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true } `

Comment: @BelminBedak { path: '', name: 'test', component: Test, pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true } }
slash dont removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130594/vuerouter-default-child-route-without-trailing-slash

Comment: <router-link to="/2018"></router-link>

Answer (score 0):

In Vue-Router v4 you can use the `strict` option:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
      ...
  ],
  strict: true, // applies to all routes
})
```

See the [sensitive and strict route options](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#Sensitive-and-strict-route-options).