# VueRouter default child route without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

VueRouter always adds a trailing slash before the path of the child route. So lets say I have a route config like this:

```
const routes = [
    path: '/home',
    components: {
        default: HomeBase
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeIndex,
            name: 'home.index'
        },
        {
            path: ':aid',
            component: HomeArticle,
            name: 'home.article'
        }
    ]
]
```

I want the routes to work like this:

- /home -> loads HomeIndex
- /home/123 -> Loads HomeArticle with :aid=123

But VueRouter always forces the trailing slash on the parent route path, when accessing a child route, so the routes work like this:

- /home/ -> loads HomeIndex
- /home/123 -> loads HomeArticle with :aid=123

This doesn't work for me, as I'm working with an application that has specific SEO requirements that require no trailing slashes.

Note that I'm using named routes to generate URLs and move between routes, so while I could link to "/home" directly, I want to use the names of routes ( "home.index") so code is more DRY. I could store the paths in constants somewhere, but the drawback of that is that you can't use the 'params' prop together with the 'path' prop when programmatically navigating.

I could split out HomeIndex as a separate path entirely, so its not a child, but I need HomeIndex and HomeArticle both to be loaded within the root HomeBase component.

Any ideas how I could achive this? Maybe through some VueRouter hooks or plugins?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1753

Comment: Not really, I think the 'strict' flag only helps with the final trailing slash of the URL, not the trailing slash of the parent path that gets always added when you access its child route

Comment: Ahh - I guess as a workaround you can prepend the route without children then?

Comment: You mean define each child route as a separate route altogether? As I mentioned in the OP, I need both child routes to render inside the parent 'HomeBase' component

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would I define it considering the example routes in OP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tried next structure which worked for me:

```
const routes = [
    path: '/home',
    components: {
        default: HomeBase
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: HomeIndex,
            name: "homeindex"
        },
        {
            path: ':aid',
            component: HomeArticle,
            name: "aid"
        }
    ]
]
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/895m3aLy/)

Using versions: `Vue - 2.5.2`, `vue-router - 3.0.1`. Routing works both using `name` and `path` without adding trailing slash at the end, i.e.:

`this.$router.push({name: "homeindex"})`

`this.$router.push("/home")`

Comment: Will this render the HomeIndex inside HomeBase when /home is accessed?

Comment: Tested it out, and when they're referenced as named routes, they still get the slash added to them. When referencing the HomeIndex route with a name, the generated URL is: /home/

Comment: I don't see names in your routes

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention this originally. Fixed the OP

Comment: Is it a must to use names when you use router?

Comment: Yes, otherwise, I have to reference the same URL in multiple places, which is anti-DRY.

Comment: I used that with names too, and works the same. No slashes at the and. And actually I see no difference because you're showing `path` not `name` in the address line.

Comment: Yup, it does, I was testing using an old build, my bad. Okay, this is so far the best solution, but it requires me to reference the full path in the child path, which is not so great when you have multiple levels of route nesting. Any ideas how to deal with that?

Comment: You can use `this.$route` to detect which path are you on at the momet and when pushing to new route just use instead of full path `this.$route.path${anotherChildPath}`. And if you want to go back use `this.router.go(-1)`.

Comment: Anyway I think you should choose between `havig a slash` or `using paths or names when routing`. )) But my point is - I've tried to show you that removing slash is possible. Kindly accept that if it worked for you so other people could see that there is a solution.

Comment: Ended up just processing my routeConfig through a helper method that converts each empty route path into its full absolute path

Comment: There is always some solution out there))